# Manually update ratings in recomender system

Tags: python, machine-learning, recommendation-engine, rating, collaborative-filtering

I developed a recommender system using Matrix Factorization in Python. The ratings are in the range [1-5]. It works very well. This system is made for client advisors rather than clients themselves. Hence, the system recommends some products to the client advisor and then this one decides which products he's gonna recommend to his client.

In my application I want to have 2  additional buttons: relevant, irrelevant. Thus, for each recommendation the client advisor would press the button irrelevant if the recommendation is not good but its rating is high and he would press the button relevant if the recommendation is good but its rating is low.

The problem is that I can't figure how to update the ratings when one of the buttons is pressed. Please give me some idea about how to handle that feature. I insist on having only two buttons (relevant and irrelevant), the client advisor can't modify the rating himself.

Thank you very much.

Comment: How is the data stored?  What did you derive your recommendations from in the first place?

Comment: In the first place I had the data in this format: [User, Product, Number of time he purchased the product]. Then I computed the ratings from that data.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment above, I would manipulate the Number of times they purchased the product field.  You need to basically transform the Number of times they purchased the product field into an implicit rating field.  I would maybe scale the product rating system to 1-5.  If they press the don't like the product button, the rating is a 1, if they press the like the product button, they get a 5.  If they have bought the product frequently, it's a 5, otherwise it starts at a 3 on the first purchase and scales up to a 4 then 5, based on your data.  If they have never bought the product AND have never rated the product, it's a null value, so won't contribute to ratings.